# How to create multiple segues from code for a VC in a Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, rubymotion

I have a VC on my storyboard and would like to present it either modally or push it on the navigation stack depending on how/where it's called.

From what I've read, I should use the `[UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:]` class method to create this segue.  However, when I call this like such:

```
    manage_friends = App.delegate.storyboard
      .instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier('ManageFriends');

    # segueWithIdentifier(NSString* identifier, source:UIViewController* source, destination:UIViewController* destination, performHandler:void (^)(void) performHandler)
    UIStoryboardSegue.segueWithIdentifier(
     'ManageFriendsPush',
      source: self,
      destination: manage_friends,
      performHandler: -> {
        pushViewController(manage_friends, animated: true)
      }
    )
```

I get an error "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar", so Im not sure if Im doing this correctly.

Is there another way to create the push segue and modal segues?

Comment: I realize that I could create these segues in the Storyboard and then call them with `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, but this is a lot less maintainable.  There are many places I'll be using this VC as a modal and would prefer to have a Segue instance to rely on.

Comment: do you have method of pushViewController? share that too, and try once with amitmated : NO

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it correctly. The method segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler: loads an already-defined segue out of a storyboard, using the identifier you use to create it in IB. It does not create a new segue.

I don't think Apple intends for developers to create segues in code.

You could load the destination scene from the storyboard using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, and then do a push or present on that destination view controller.

I've often wondered if you could create a new segue using alloc followed by initWithIdentifier:source:destination, but have never tried it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this method, but Im still confused as to why there are params for source and destination view controllers.  Would those not inherently be setup in the segue? Also, it's placed under the "Creating a Custom Segue" in the docs. And the `identifier` attribute seems to be used to name the segue per it's description.